# Oracle (SQL Developer) setting parameters

Tags: oracle

Just wondering, can you set a parameter in a Oracle script similar to MySql's

```
SET @var := 1;
```

If so, how?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var  num NUMBER;
begin
  :num := 1;
end;
/
```